# Custom Configuration with multiple nested collections

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.5, app-config

I know there are a lot of answers out there already for this, however, none of the answers I've read seem to be quite what i'm after as when I try to match up the examples with what i'm doing, they don't quite sit right.  So bear with me on this one.

I'm trying to create a custom nested configuration for the app.config file in c#.  What i'm after is essentially this:

```
<MyConfigurationSection>
    <CollectionA>
      <CollectionC Property1="Blah" Property2="123" >
        <CollectionD Property1="Achoo" Property2="Bless You">
            <Element Property1="Woo" Property2="Hoo" Property3="456" />
            <Element Property1="Oh" Property2="No" />
        </CollectionD>
        <CollectionD Property1="TaDa" Property2="HaHa!">
            <Element Property1="X" Property2="Y" />
        </CollectionD>
      </CollectionC>
    </CollectionA>
    <CollectionB>
        <CollectionC Property1="Boo" Property2="789">
            <CollectionD Property1="Test" Property2="ing">
                <Element Property1="Please" Property2="Help" />
            </CollectionD>
        </CollectionC>
    </CollectionB>
</MyConfigurationSection>
```

I've written the code for a custom configuration section, When it was just `CollectionA` and `CollectionB` with Elements, not a problem, but changes required in the application mean I need something a little more complex.  Any help, or anyone point me in the right direction please?

As I say, I've looked at other examples, and they all seem to be `CollectionB`, nested in `CollectionA` in a `config` section - which just doesn't seem to help me, or maybe i'm just misunderstanding something.

Ultimately, what i'm trying to achieve is, for `collectionA`, map all `CollectionC`'s into an object, and each `CollectionC` object has it's own properties, along with a mapping of `CollectionD` objects (with a list of Element).  Then repeat for `CollectionB`.

For completeness, this was the custom assembly I've created for it, obviously it doesn't work, and I was reluctant to post initially as I feel like I was so far off the track, it probably wasn't worth the effort.  But none the less, it's here:

```
namespace my.app.namespace
{
    #region Configuration Section

    public class MyConfigurationSection : ConfigurationSection
    {
       public const string SectionName = "MyConfigurationSection";

       [ConfigurationProperty("CollectionA")]
       public CollectionA CollectionAItems
       {
           get { return ((CollectionA)(base["CollectionA"])); }
           set { base["CollectionA"] = value; }
       }

       [ConfigurationProperty("CollectionB")]
       public CollectionB CollectionBItems
       {
           get { return ((CollectionB)(base["CollectionB"])); }
           set { base["CollectionB"] = value; }
       }
    }

    #endregion Configuration Section

    #region Configuration Collections

    //CollectionA that wraps the CollectionC
    [ConfigurationCollection(typeof(ElementC))]
    public class CollectionA : ConfigurationElementCollection
    {

       protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
       {
           return new ElementC();
       }

       protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
       {
           return ((ElementC)element).Property1;
       }

       protected override string ElementName
       {
           get
           {
               return "CollectionA";
           }
       }

        [ConfigurationProperty("CollectionC")]
        public CollectionC CollectionCItems
        {
            get { return ((CollectionC)(base["CollectionC"])); }
            set { base["CollectionC"] = value; }
        }
    }

    //CollectionB that wraps CollectionC
    [ConfigurationCollection(typeof(ElementC))]
    public class CollectionB : ConfigurationElementCollection
    {
       protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
       {
           return new ElementC();
       }

       protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
       {
           return ((ElementC)element).Property1;
       }

       protected override string ElementName
       {
           get
           {
               return "CollectionB";
           }
       }

       [ConfigurationProperty("CollectionC")]
        public CollectionC CollectionCItems
        {
            get { return ((CollectionC)(base["CollectionC"])); }
            set { base["CollectionC"] = value; }
        }
    }

    //CollectionC that wraps CollectionD
    [ConfigurationCollection(typeof(ElementD))]
    public class CollectionC : ConfigurationElementCollection
    {
        protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
        {
            return new ElementD();
        }

        protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
        {
            return ((ElementD)element).Property1;
        }

        protected override string ElementName
        {
            get
            {
                return "CollectionC";
            }
        }

        [ConfigurationProperty("CollectionD")]
        public CollectionD CollectionDItems
        {
            get { return ((CollectionD)(base["CollectionD"])); }
            set { base["CollectionD"] = value; }
        }
    }

    #endregion Configuration Collections

    #region Configuration Elements

    //ElementC (element of CollectionC)
    class ElementC : ConfigurationElement
    {
       [ConfigurationProperty("Property1", DefaultValue = "", IsKey = true, IsRequired = true)]
       public string Property1
       {
           get { return (string)this["Property1"]; }
           set { this["Property1"] = value; }
       }

       [ConfigurationProperty("Property2", DefaultValue = "", IsKey = false, IsRequired = true)]
       public int Property2
       {
           get { return (int)this["Property2"]; }
           set { this["Property2"] = value; }
       }
    }

    //ElementD (element of CollectionD)
    class ElementD : ConfigurationElement
    {
       [ConfigurationProperty("Property1", DefaultValue = "", IsKey = true, IsRequired = true)]
       public string Property1
       {
           get { return (string)this["Property1"]; }
           set { this["Property1"] = value; }
       }

       [ConfigurationProperty("Property2", DefaultValue = "", IsKey = false, IsRequired = true)]
       public string Property2
       {
           get { return (string)this["Property2"]; }
           set { this["Property2"] = value; }
       }
    }

    //Element
    class Element : ConfigurationElement
    {
        [ConfigurationProperty("Property1", DefaultValue = "", IsKey = true, IsRequired = true)]
        public string Property1
        {
            get { return (string)this["Property1"]; }
            set { this["Property1"] = value; }
        }

        [ConfigurationProperty("Property2", DefaultValue = "", IsKey = false, IsRequired = true)]
        public string Property2
        {
            get { return (string)this["Property2"]; }
            set { this["Property2"] = value; }
        }

        [ConfigurationProperty("Property3", DefaultValue = "", IsKey = false, IsRequired = false)]
        public int Property3
        {
            get { return (int)this["Property3"]; }
            set { this["Property3"] = value; }
        }
    }

    #endregion Configuration Elements  
}
```

Naturally the header of the config file contains the appropriate `configSections` section:

```
<configSections>
    <section name="MyConfigurationSection" type="my.app.namespace.MyConfigurationSection, my.app.namespace" />
</configSections>
```

In order to access the config, I've got the below:

```
//Fails on this line
var configSection = ConfigurationManager.GetSection(MyConfigurationSection.SectionName) as MyConfigurationSection;

foreach (CollectionA collectionAItems in configSection.CollectionAItems)
{
    //It doesn't even make it into this for each but essentially i'd iterate over collection C, and then each CollectionD in C, and then each Element in CollectionD
}
```

As I've said further up, I think i'm quite a way off on what i'm trying to achieve!  I tried to make `CollectionA` and `CollectionB` into their own `configSections` to break it up a little, but didn't make much progress on that either.

Comment: Did you check those questions? What they show is that you need to create your own *separate* assembly, reference it in your project *and* the `configsections` section in app.config before you can read the settings. It's a lot easier to use .NET Core's configuration feature in the Full framework. The packages target .NET Standard 2.0 which means they can be used from the Full framework without problems. This would allow you to pull settings from XML, JSON or a database and map it to strongly-typed objects without extra assemblies and references

Comment: I've got my own assembly, with code for reading a custom config section.  That was all fine.  As I said in my question, When it's just a config section, with a custom collection (or two collections) and each collection with a series of elements, I'm able to iterate over them and get the values/map to my object etc.  I'll have a look at the .Net Core's configuration Framework though if it's simpler to use.  Thanks

Comment: What's the question then? CollectionA needs to be an object that contains CollectionC items. CollectionC needs to contain CollectionD items. What do those classes look like? They should match the XML schema. If you need any kind of mapping, it should be applied *after* the configuration objects are loaded

Comment: You've only posted the XML you want to use, not the configuration classes. If there's any mismatch, it's in those classes. BTW that's another advantage of the new Configuration system - you don't need to map the structure completely, or match type and element names, you can read and deserialize specific sections

Comment: That's correct, the `CollectionA` and `CollectionB` need to contain `CollectionC`, each `CollectionC` will contain `CollectionD`'s which in turn will have the `Element`'s.  I didn't post the code, as I thought I was way off the track.  However, I'll add the code I have into the question.

Comment: If you have any links for the new Configuration system with some good examples, it'd be appreciated (I've started to have a quick look)

Comment: I've used [this MSDN Magazine article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt632279.aspx) to add configuration to multiple console applications, some of them targetting the Full framework. In some cases I mixed both file and database providers

Comment: The [Configuration in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.2) article is even more detailed. It's not specific to ASP.NET Core, despite the title. In a console application you use the `ConfigurationBuilder` class directly instead of `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder`. And finally, there's the [Generic Host](Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting) that allows you to combine .NET Core-style DI, Configuration, logging into worker-style applications. Despite the ASP.NET Core references, it's still a .NET Standard 2.0 library